# Using html text area with variable max character per line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

The text area should support different max character per line depending on the number of lines it has.

Example,

6 max chars when it's 1 line.

15 max chars per line when it's 2 lines.

20 max chars per line when it's 3 lines. and so on.

Imagine that the size of the text area is fixed and the number of characters and their size should alter accordingly to fill the text area. So when it's multiline, the fonts shall be smaller and the max number of characters per line shall increase as well.

I believe javascript and jquery will be needed here.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you try?? jsfiddle pls

Answer (score 0):

Your question says, you want to use single textarea tag to accomplish your task. 
Eventhough your textarea size is fixed, we cannot say the typed words will reach its end because each character has some different size(width) (ex. @,+,A,>)
I suguest you to use unique textboxes or textarea (to get input lines that satisfy your condition) to accomplish your task. From that separate textbox or textarea, you can combine what you want. 
I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this with textarea alone. what you can do is set max character length for multiple textareas below each other and use visual styling to make it look one box. Setting the font size of each textarea from css can be done to make the size smaller in each box.